# PHP APC CLI opcode cache has no effect

Tags: php, command-line-interface, apc

i want to use apc as cli with opcode cache feature.

using `apc.enable_cli` to true. but noting happened in benchmark time and memory usage.

```
; php.ini
apc.enable_cli = 1
```

but in web based usage different. i see how work apc and do magic for running php scripts.
about half memory usage also about 0.01 faster than normal run php script.

but i think php dont use opcode cache during using apc in cli. how can i use it. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect apc to give any improvement in performance on the command line, because the apc cache is going to be dropped every run.

Comment: so how can i imporve complex cli applications in php?

Comment: Profile your app using xdebug+kcachegrind and figure out where the slow bits are. apc is really not going to be the answer for CLI apps.